# Why do static functions eliminate undefined symbols in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, linker, iokit

I am attempting to use I/O kit and have linked to I/O kit properly.

When I use a function in I/O kit and don't call it within a static function, I get the following error `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`.

Here is an example to suppress the error

```
static void test(void)
{
    if (IORegisterForSystemPower(...)) 
    {

    }
}
```

Here is an example that will cause the error.

```
void test(void)
{
    if (IORegisterForSystemPower(...)) 
    {

    }
}
```

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

EDIT:

Here are the exact error messages:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_IORegisterForSystemPower", referenced from:
      _registerNotificaitonUsingIOKit in AppDelegate.o
  "_IONotificationPortGetRunLoopSource", referenced from:
      _registerNotificaitonUsingIOKit in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Can you paste the complete list of error messages? For example does it complain about the symbol IORegisterForSystemPower?

Comment: I'v added error messages. Please see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I got one scenario when this can happen. If the static function is never called, you won't get that link time error.

For example, I wrote a simple c file with this function, and `undef_foobar` is not defined:

```
static int foobar (void) 
{
    undef_foobar ();
}
```

Now, if `foobar()` is called from my `main()`, I get the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_undef_foobar", referenced from:
```

If the function isn't called at all from within this c file, there are no linker errors.

Comment: I tried your example and Xcode warns me of the undefined function `Implicit declaration of function "undef_foobar" is invalid in C99`. Would you mind trying to link and then call a function from I/O kit to see if you get the same linker issues?